# Why/when would it be recommended to release locks in reverse order?

Tags: concurrency, locking

In [this article](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/stm/article.html) about Software Transactional Memory I found this note:

> It is also recommended to release locks in the reverse order from which they were acquired.

Why would this be recommended? In what scenarios? It seems to me that it'd be more beneficial to release locks as soon as possible in whatever order.

Comment: If you down-vote, please do it constructively and add an explanation why, so that the question can be improved.

Comment: It's a valid question, not sure why someone would down vote it.